# Set link of class to different color (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

so I have two sets of links in an HTML document. Most of them (any normal link showing up on the site) have been set to my desired color, but I want four of them to have a different color and hover color than the others.

I set `<a class="other" href="/">different link</a>` on those links in my HTML and

> a.other { color:fff; }
>
> a.other:hover { color: #8741ff; }

in my CSS, but the links of `.other` are still showing up like all the rest.

Is there a way to rectify this?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left out the hash sign (`#`) before `fff`. :)

Comment: Oh, oops... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
a.other:link,
a.other:visited {
   color: #ffffff;
}
a.other:hover,
a.other:focus {
    color: #ffcc00;
}
```

I think that should do it. You have to use the pseudo-attribute of the link element a.classname:link I guess. And yes, you omitted the hashtag.